# QProcess won't start process on Windows (but works on Linux and OSX)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyqt5, qprocess

I am currently working on a signal analyzing program with a GUI, which should run on Linux, OSX and Windows. For some reason this program won't run on Windows, but I don't get any Error Messages. More precisely my main program (GUI) fails to spawn my subprocess that should analyze the data and send the results to the GUI.

The only thing I found online was that Windows needs

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

to run processes correctly if they are created using the multiprocessing module. Sadly, adding this part didn't solve the problem for Qprocess.

I wrote a pretty simple script that has the same problem and communicates like my complex scripts.

Here my main GUI process:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5 import uic
import pickle

class MyGuiApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('process_gui.ui', self)

        
        # Set puchButtons
        self.stop_pB.setEnabled(False)
        self.start_pB.clicked.connect(self.start_measurement)
        self.stop_pB.clicked.connect(self.stop_measurement)

        # Initialising Subprocess
        self.my_process = QtCore.QProcess()
        self.my_process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.new_data)

    def start_measurement(self):
        self.stop_pB.setEnabled(True)
        self.start_pB.setEnabled(False)

        self.my_process.start('python3', ['main_subprocess.py'])

    def stop_measurement(self):
        self.stop_pB.setEnabled(False)
        self.start_pB.setEnabled(True)

        self.my_process.terminate()

    def new_data(self):
        data = self.my_process.readAllStandardOutput()
        # unpickle data -> string
        stdout_str = pickle.loads(data)

        self.label.setText(stdout_str)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MyGuiApp()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

'''

Here my Subprocess:

```
   import time
   import sys
   import pickle

   index = 0
   while True:
      start = time.time()

      sys.stdout.buffer.write(pickle.dumps(str(index)))
      sys.stdout.flush()

      index = index + 1
      time.sleep(0.5-(time.time()-start)) # sets loop runtime to 0.5 secs
```

And here the .ui file in case someone wants to run my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
      <property name="title">
       <string>GroupBox</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="start_pB">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Start</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="stop_pB">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Stop</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>20</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>DATA</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: good work so far, but what exactly is the question please ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How do I need to change the code so that the subprocess spawns on a windows pc. As mentioned this code works fine on OSX and Linux but not windows. I don't know why as I don't get any Error Messages.

Comment: If one presses 'Start' in the GUI-window the subprocess should start and send a string. If on presses 'Start' on a windows Pc nothing the subprocess won't spawn but the rest of the GUI works fine. Closing the GUI will give Exit Code 0 just like everything work fine but it obviously didn't.

Comment: windows works differently to linux and ios.  unless you have imported modules from subdirectories and other files should use the full path ie. c:\folder\filder\file.py

Comment: This didn't work either, I also tried giving the Qprocess a wrong path to see wether i get any Error Message but nothing happened. It seems like there is nothing happening at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run this in a `windows 10` environment using the `VS code` editor.

I made no changes to the code whatsoever.
I did this:

1. I created the `process_gui.ui` file
2. I created the `main_subprocess.py` file
3. I replicted the code in the question

This works.

It produces this:
[image]

And when i press the `start` button it initiates a counter like this:

[image]

So i can confirm that the code does run on windows.
I hope that this helps you or at least confirms that it does run.

Given that the code works, you should not look at the environment settings.

Comment: Thank you for testing. I did some more testing and found out that i am getting the Error Code 0 (The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.) when trying to start the process. I double checked my path (absolute path) but it still doesn't work. Any Idea what to do next?

Comment: which editor are you using ? how is it setup ? are you pointing to the correct version of python ?

Comment: i am using Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with the help of the qt-forum and @D.L's comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/135863/qprocess-not-working-on-windows-works-fine-on-linux-and-osx/5

Additional to `if __name__=='__main__':` one has to change 2 things in order to run my code on Windows.

1. Don't call python3 but give Qprocess the absolute path to the `python.exe`. Note that even though im running python3 it is called `python.exe` inside a Python3X folder, like: `r'C:\Users\me\AppData\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python'`
2. The same is true for the script you want run. Give the QProcess the whole absoltue path, like: `r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\dummyfolder\main_subprocess.py`'.

For some reason `QProcess::terminate()`, which should be triggered once you press 'Stop', does not work now. The state of the Subprocess stays in 2 (*The process is running and is ready for reading and writing.*) but `QProcess::kill()` works fine for me.

`

Comment: i am glad to have helped & pleased that it is now solved.